# How to select sibling branch only of TreeView with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, treeview, siblings

I have a multi-level treeview using KendoUI from Telerik and I'm trying to get the correct Id's for the branch of a re-ordered node.

```
    <ul id="root">
    <li>Item 1 (1)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="1" />
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1.1 (5)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="5" /></li>
            <li>Item 1.2 (6)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="6" />
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 1.2.1 (11)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="11" /></li>
                    <li>Item 1.2.2 (12)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="12" /></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 2 (2)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="2" />
        <ul>
            <li>Item 2.1 (7)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="7" />
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 2.1.1 (13)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="13" />
                        <ul>
                            <li>Item 2.1.1.1 (18)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="18" /></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Item 2.1.2 (14)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="14" /></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Item 2.2 (8)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="8" />
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 2.2.1 (15)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="15" /></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Item 2.3 (27)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="27" /></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 3 (3)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="3" />
        <ul>
            <li>Item 3.1 (9)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="9" />
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 3.1.1 (16)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="16" /></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Item 3.2 (10)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="10" />
                <ul>
                    <li>Item.3.2.1 (23)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="23" /></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Item 3.3 (19)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="19" />
                <ul>
                    <li>Item.3.3.1 (24)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="24" /></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Item 3.4 (20)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="20" />
                <ul>
                    <li>Item.3.4.1 (25)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="25" /></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Item 3.5 (21)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="21" />
                <ul>
                    <li>Item.3.5.1 (28)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="28" /></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Item 3.6 (22)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="22" />
                <ul>
                    <li>Item.3.6.1 (26)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="26" /></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 4 (4)<input type="hidden" name="PresetItemId" value="4" /></li>
</ul>
```

My thought is that each parent contains children, and those children are independently sort-ordered from any other branch in the TreeView.

So I need to grab all the siblings of the branch that the node is dropped onto and get the id's for only that branch level when the node is being sorted.  If any of those nodes have children, I do not want the children to be a part of the Id collection.

I have it working, somewhat, but it's returning all the siblings (which is correct), but also all the children of those siblings (which is not correct).

```
var treeview;

function onTreeViewDragEnd(e){
    var console = $("#console");
    //alert("source: " + treeview.text(e.sourceNode));
    //alert("destination: " + treeview.text(e.destinationNode));

    var list = $(e.destinationNode).siblings().not($(this).children());

    var data = $("input", list).serialize();
    console.html(JSON.stringify(data));
}


treeview = $("#root").kendoTreeView({
    dragAndDrop : true,
    dragend: onTreeViewDragEnd
}).data("kendoTreeView");
```

I've started a jsfiddle on this: http://jsfiddle.net/kahanu/PdaRg/1/

To use this example, simply expand a node and then drop it somewhere else on the same branch and it will display the hidden input values for the branch (and the children, which is not what I want).

Any help pointing me in the right direction is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that you're fetching more nodes than you need to, it's that you're searching for `input` at any level below the nodes.

```
var list = $(e.destinationNode).siblings();
var data = list.children("div").find("input").serialize();
```

Comment: David, thanks, I see what you mean. Your solution is a lot closer.  This returns almost the correct nodes (and values).  It's missing one node, the node that I'm dropping in front of.  Also, what does ".children("div")" do?  There is not "div" in the tree.

Comment: I found what I needed with David's help. His code returned just nodes on that level which is what I wanted, but it wasn't returning all the nodes on that level.  Whichever node I'm dropping in front of, would not appear in my list.

I found that the .siblings() returns all the nodes except the current node.  I found that going up to the parent and back to children would select all the nodes on that level.
`var list = $(e.destinationNode).parent().children(); <-- not .siblings()
    var data = list.children("div").find("input").serialize();`

Comment: You could also do `.siblings().andSelf()` which does exactly what you're requesting.

Comment: Yup, I just tried that and you are right.  Hmmm, I think I like this one better.  Thanks.